# $xy\leq x^2+y^2$ is a naive form of Cauchy Schwarz?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In class, my professor explained that $xy\leq x^2+y^2$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ is a naive form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Is this true and how can I see this?

Comment: It’s certainly a result of CS. For $u=(x,y)$ and $v=(y,x)$ Then you get $u\cdot v=2xy, $ and $u\cdot u=v\cdot v=x^2+y^2.$ So CS says $(2xy)^2\leq (x^2+y^2)^2$ and thus $2|xy|\leq x^2+y^2,$ and $xy\leq 2|xy|.$

Comment: What do you mean by naive? Do you mean weak form?

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I think my professor meant simple or trivial

Comment: Yeah, naive is a strange choice of words.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews if you put that as an answer I will mark it as accepted

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Steele calls it a "humble" bound in his book.

Comment: The question should probably be closed - it has to duplicate some question here. Hence, I put it in a comment.

Comment: The irony is if you would ask a student to prove this instead of the stronger $2xy\le x^2+y^2$, they would maybe not succeed because rearranging will not lead to something you can nicely factorise.

Comment: Another simple reasoning:  if $xy \le 0$, easy.  If $x,y<0$ replace with $-x,-y$.  So it suffices to do the case $x,y > 0$.  In fact, depending on which is larger, either $xy \le x^2$ or $xy \le y^2$, and thus in both cases $xy \le x^2+y^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not exactly the CS inequality. But there are several ways to see this. Observe for example:
$$
0 \leq (x-y)^2 = x^2+y^2-2xy
$$
Rearrange to get
$$
xy \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2).
$$

Or another way to see this: Use that $\log$ is concave.
$$
\log\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2 \right) \geq \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(x^2) + \log(y^2) \right)= \frac{1}{2}\log(x^2y^2) = \log\left(\sqrt {x^2y^2} \right) = \log(\lvert xy \rvert) 
$$
Take the exponential on both sides to see an even better version of the last inequality.

There are literally dozens of proofs.

This inequality is a special case of the very important Young inequality. It can be used to prove Hölder's inequality a special case of which is the CS inequality.

Comment: Yeah the first way is the most standard way of deducing this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality of Cauchy-Schwarz is :
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \forall x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n \in \mathbb{R}, \left(x_1 y_1 + \cdots + x_n y_n\right)^2 \leq \left(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2\right) \left(y_1^2 + \cdots + y_n^2\right)$$
When $n = 2$, $x_1 = y_2 = a$ and $x_2 = y_1 = b$ and we have :
$$\left(a b + b a\right)^2 \leq \left(a^2 + b^2\right) \left(b^2 + a^2\right)$$
We deduce that :
$$a b \leq \dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{2} \leq a^2 + b^2$$